# Write XML using arcpy (Arcview license)

Tags: python, xml, arcgis

I need to generate xml of attribute data of a feature, but I have only Arcview license so, I can't use Export XML tool. What are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Python has everything you need already included in the standard library. Below is code that opens a searchcursor on a shapefile featureclass and dumps selected fields and their values to an xml element.  When all the rows are finished, it dumps the top, aggregated element to an xml file.  Notice I'm using an arcpy.da searchcursor which is only available at 10.1, but you can easily modify the code to work with regular arcpy searchcursors (or updatecursors for that matter).

```python
#in some cases cElementTree won't be available, but it's lots faster,
#so get it if we can
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

import arcpy

def rows_as_dicts(cursor):
    '''
    Yields rows from passed Arcpy da cursor as dicts
    '''
    colnames = cursor.fields
    uc = hasattr(cursor, 'updateRow')
    for row in cursor:
        row_object = dict(zip(colnames, row))
        yield row_object
        if uc:
            cursor.updateRow([row_object[colname] for colname in colnames])

def dump2xml(row, stands, elelst):
    '''
    Builds the xml tree from the passed row dict
    '''

    # stand level creation
    stand = et.Element("stand")

    stand.set("tractid", row['TRACTID'])
    stand.set('stand', str(row['STAND']))

    # add field elements with their values
    for e in elelst:
        xele = et.SubElement(stand, e)
        xele.text = str(row[e])

    #add to top level stands element
    stands.append(stand)

def main():
    #establish top level element
    stands = et.Element("stands")

    #set fields to output to xml
    fields = ('MAPNAME ACRES TYP PROGRAM SI AGE YR').split()

    #get cursor going and make the xml elements
    fc = 'c:/arcview/sf/summerville/stand.shp'
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['*']) as sc:
        for row in rows_as_dicts(sc):
            dump2xml(row, stands, fields)

    #throw the entire xml tree to a file        
    xmltree = et.ElementTree(stands)
    xmltree.write('c:/temp/stands.xml', encoding='UTF-8')

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

good luck to you,

Mike